# generate Jquery Multilevel menu list with ul li

Tags: jquery, html-lists, multi-level

```
...images
......|vertical
......|horizontal
...Jquery
......|UI
......|include
...quickfox
```

**Array to process:**
I have folder structure Like above.And it is stored in array dirs. see below

```
var dirs = [ 
        "images",
        "images/vertical",
        "images/horizontal",
        "Jquery",
        "Jquery/UI",
        "Jquery/include",
        "quickfox"
        ];
```

**Objective:** How Can I make nested ul li as below.

```
<ul id="categorymenu">
    <li>images </li>
    <ul>
        <li>vertical</li>
        <li>horizontal</li>
    </ul>
    <li>Jquery</li>
    <ul>
        <li>UI</li>
        <li>include</li>
    </ul>
    <li>quickfox</li>
</ul>
```

**UPDATE: XML STRUCTURE**

```
<directory name="images">
   <file path="BBB.gif" width="500" height="282">BBB.gif</file>
   <file path="AAA.jpg" width="964" height="525">AAA.jpg</file>
   <directory name="images/vertical">
      <file path="CCC.jpg" width="964" height="525">CCC.jpg</file>
   </directory>
   <directory name="images/horizontal">
      <file path="DDD.jpg" width="964" height="525">DDD.jpg</file>      
   </directory>
</directory>
```

This is where I make array from xml ..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //------ READ XML -----------
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "___deck.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (data) {
            my_xml = data;
            xmlDirParser(my_xml);
        }
    });
    //------ Get Files on List Change  -----------
    $("#dirlist").change(function () {
        var folder = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
        xmlFileParser(folder, my_xml);
    });
});

function xmlDirParser(my_xml) {
    $(my_xml).find('directory').each(function () {
        var dirname = $(this).attr('name');
        // $('#dirlist').append('<option value="1">'+dirname+'</option>');
        //This is where I get dirs array
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

If you change your data structure to multi dimensional arrays/objects can use a recursive function to loop through infinite nesting levels as follows:

```
var dirs = [{
    name: "images",
    subdir: [{
        name: "vertical"
    }, {
        name: "horizontal"
    }]
}, {
    name: "Jquery",
    subdir: [{
        name: "UI", subdir: [{name:'Nested 1',subdir: [{name:'Nested 2',subdir: [{name:'Nested 3'}]}]}]
    }, {
        name: "include"
    }]
}, {
    name: "quickfox"
}];

function createList( array){
    var html='<ul>';
    $.each( array, function(k, item){
        html+='<li>'+item.name;
        if( item.subdir){
            html+=createList(item.subdir);
        }
        html+='</li>';
    });
     html+='</ul>';
    return html;
}


$('body').html( createList( dirs))
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/AA6yb/1

**REVISED ANSWER**

Based on updated information that xml already has nesting, issue is how to parse xml not flat array.

Following recursively loops through all directories in xml that are `children`. By using `find()` you sinply created a flat array since `find()` looks for all descendents

```
function createList($xml) {
    var html = '';

    $xml.children('directory').each(function () {
        var $dir = $(this);
        var name= $dir.attr('name');
        html += '<li class="dir">' + parseName($dir.attr('name'));
        if ($dir.children().length) {
            html += '<ul>';
            $dir.children('file').each(function () {
                html += '<li class="file">' + $(this).attr('path') + '</li>';
            });
            /* recursively loop through children directories of this directory*/
            if( $dir.children('directory').length){
                html+=createList($dir);
            }
            html += '</ul>';
        }
    });
    html += '</li>';
    return html;
}
function parseName( name){
    if( name.indexOf('/')>-1){
        return name.split('/').pop();
    }else{
        return name;
    }
}

$('#directory_list').html(createList($(xmlData)))
```

HTML

```
<ul id="directory_list"></ul>
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/AA6yb/2/

Comment: Thank you @charlietfl.

1- How Can I convert var dirs as in question to multil dim array.Because these entries are from xml.
2-How can we add indenting to this code for beautification.

Comment: are you parsing xml at server or in javascript AJAX request? If javascript; provide sample of xml

Comment: I have added xml and javascript in question.

Comment: made question a lot more difficult by displaying a flat array. Your xml has nesting already, no need to convert to flat array.Problem is you are ignoring xml nesting by using `find('directory`) and not `children('directory')` and then recursively looping through that directory's children if they exist

Comment: Can you suggest the corrected code ? with children('directory)

Comment: This code seems to be creating empty <ul></ul> where it cant find subfolder ? check output source of http://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/TX2d8/

Answer (score 4):

Structure of your array is not useful for creating elements, you can create an object based on the array and use this object instead.

```
var o = {}; 

// Creating an object based on the array elements
$.each(dirs, function (_, value) {
    if (value.indexOf('/') === -1) {
        o[value] = [];
    } else {
        var arr = value.split('/');
        o[arr[0]].push(arr[1]);
    }
});

// Creating elements

var html = '<ul id="categorymenu">';
for (key in o) {
    html += '<li>' + key + '</li>';
    if (o[key].length) {
        html += '<ul><li>' + o[key].join('</li><li>') + '</li></ul>';
    }
}
html += '</ul>';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5DuDp/

**Update**:

I didn't notice that the intended markup is invalid, an `ul` element should only have `li` child elements, you should add the descendant `ul` element to the `li` element:

```
for (key in o) {
    html += '<li>' + key ;
    if (o[key].length) {
        html += '<ul><li>' + o[key].join('</li><li>') + '</li></ul>';
    }
    html += '</li>';
}
html += '</ul>';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/642pr/

Comment: your code works fine but what is this `_` in `function (_, value)` ?

Comment: @Bingo That's the index, `_` is a valid identifier in JavaScript, consider it as `i` or `index`.

Answer (score 1):

If you must have this data structure you can use this:

```
$(function () {
    var dirs = [
        "images",
        "images/vertical",
        "images/horizontal",
        "Jquery",
        "Jquery/UI",
        "Jquery/include",
        "quickfox"];

    var rootList = $("<ul id='categorymenu'>").appendTo("body");
    var elements = {};

    $.each(dirs, function () {
        var parent = elements[this.substr(0, this.lastIndexOf("/"))];
        var list = parent ? parent.next("ul") : rootList;
        var textMenu= parent ? this.split("/")[1] : this;
        if (!list.length) {
            list = $("<ul>").insertAfter(parent);
        }
        var item = $("<li>").appendTo(list);
        $("<a>").text(textMenu).appendTo(item);
        elements[this] = item;
    });
});
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/K8SZk/3/