# How to convert simple html list to multilevel using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, google-web-designer

I have this code

in HTML:

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href=''>Item</a></li>
    <li><a href=''>_subitem</a></li>
    <li><a href=''>_subitem</a></li>
    <li><a href=''>_subitem</a></li>
    <li><a href=''>__sub-subitem</a></li>
    <li><a href=''>__sub-subitem</a></li>
</ul>
```

Looks like this in browser:

```
    Item
        _subitem
        _subitem
        _subitem
            __sub-subitem
            __sub-subitem
```

Now I want a **jquery** solution to convert the above code to **nested unordered HTML** list like below.

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href=''>Item</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href=''>subitem</a></li>
            <li><a href=''>subitem</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href=''>subitem</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href=''>sub-subitem</a></li>
                    <li><a href=''>sub-subitem</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        <ul>
    </li>
<ul>
```

Please someone help me I am not finding any solution for this.

Comment: Please check this link , might be it's helpful to you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15851418/generate-jquery-multilevel-menu-list-with-ul-li

Comment: Can you please share the code which can help me to make multilevel list.?

Comment: Please see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15851418/generate-jquery-multilevel-menu-list-with-ul-li

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I count '_' for find level of sub items and also store each level's parent in parentLi variable which is an array and append each sub item to itself parent.

```js
function doIt() {
  let ul = document.createElement("ul");
  let parentLi = [];
  $("ul li a").each(function() {
    let level = ($(this).text().match(/_/g) || []).length;
    if (level === 0) {
      let li = document.createElement("li");
      let a = document.createElement("a");
      a.innerHTML = $(this).text()
      li.append(a);
      parentLi[level + 1] = li;
      ul.append(li);
    } else if (level > 0) {
      let ul = document.createElement("ul");
      let li = document.createElement("li");
      let a = document.createElement("a");
      a.innerHTML = $(this).text().replaceAll('_', '')
      li.append(a);
      parentLi[level + 1] = li;
      ul.append(li);
      parentLi[level].append(ul);
    }
  });
  $('#menu').append(ul);
};

doIt();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href=''>Item</a></li>
  <li><a href=''>_subitem</a></li>
  <li><a href=''>__sub-subitem</a></li>
  <li><a href=''>__sub-subitem</a></li>
  <li><a href=''>_subitem</a></li>
  <li><a href=''>_subitem</a></li>
  <li><a href=''>Item1</a></li>
  <li><a href=''>_subitem</a></li>
  <li><a href=''>__sub-subitem</a></li>
  <li><a href=''>__sub-subitem</a></li>
  <li><a href=''>_subitem</a></li>
  <li><a href=''>_subitem</a></li>
  <li><a href=''>__sub-subitem</a></li>
  <li><a href=''>__sub-subitem</a></li>
</ul>


<div id='menu'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, buddy your answer is awesome! I just modified the code and turn it into a jquery plugin see my code below. If there is something is bad you can make the correction.

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to post the code but your answer is 100% right.